# Aryeh Kaplan and Talmud memorization

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, memory

Aryeh Kaplan’s Jewish Meditation, page 27:

> I recall that when I was in yeshivah, a few friends and I decided to have a contest to see who could memorize the most pages of Talmud. For me, it was an interesting experience. The first page took considerable effort and time, perhaps several hours. As I continued, each page became progressively easier. Eventually, after ten pages or so, I found that I could memorize a page after three or four readings. By the time I had gone through some twenty pages, I could memorize a page with a single reading. What had originally been extremely difficult had become relatively easy.  My friends reported the same experience.

Any personal or recorded (similar or of greater value) success stories of this?

[I ask specifically from a corner of Torah study in pertaining to Judaism and it’s Torah study]

Comment: Doesn't say if he was speaking of word-memorization or content alone. (Re. the latter, see [R. Yehuda of Modena](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leon_of_Modena)'s [Lev Ha'aryeh](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/37392) for memory techniques and R. Yehoshua Cohen (AKA "Shas Cohen") in describing proper methodology to study and review Talmud and successfully committing it to memory.)

Comment: *Cohen in his 'Kerem Yehoshua' describing...

Comment: @Oliver Even memorizing the content of each amud of Talmud in one read is amazing! :D

Comment: Once I heard something that to be admitted to the jeshivah of Lublin before the war, you had to know something like 20 dafim by heart.

Comment: Does it help in understanding the Talmud? Do people with phenomenal memory automatically excel in understanding and interpreting?

Comment: @Kazibácsi Pretty sure it was 200 (!). IIRC was reported so by various alumni.

Comment: @Kazibácsi According to Wikipedia, the entrance exam required mastery of some 400 (!) dafim: מבחני הקבלה דרשו שליטה במסכתות יומא, פסחים, ביצה, ברכות ושבת בגמרא, עם מפרשים - בסך הכל מעל ל-400 דפי גמרא. https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F

Comment: @IsraelReader Interesting, though no source is provided there. OTOH my sources are alumni themselves who attested to the official admission requirements (R. Pinchas Hirschprung, R. David Halachmi and I think R. Nosson Lubart also mentioned it in his She'erit Nattan; these are a few that I recall off-hand).

Comment: Also no source provided on R. Pinchas Hirschprung's Wiki page. "After Rabbi Shapiro died in 1933, Rabbi Hirschprung would test prospective students for admittance to the Chachmei Lublin Yeshiva, where entry required the memorization 200 Talmudic folio pages (400 column pages). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhas_Hirschprung

Comment: @IsraelReader Re. R. Hirschprung as one of the testers, he personally said this over at a memorial for R. Shapiro (in Brooklyn, NY), while others also attested to his rôle. Re. the entrance requirement of 200 *dafim*, aside for Mandelbaum repeating this -without a particular source- in his documentary 'ישיבת חכמי לובלין' (Jer. 1994, vol. 1 p. 327) I heard this fact from my father who heard it directly from many alumni that he knew (Rabbis Gelfbish, Moskowitz, Rotenberg).